# Mimicking PSQL seed/re-seed file in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, psql

I'm currently working with Firestore for the first time after primarily using PSQL.

When I am working with test data in PSQL, I usually write a seed file that can clear my database ('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS' etc...) and re-seed it with test data when I run the file in Node.

Is there a way to mimick this with Firestore?

I currently have a file that will insert all test data into Firestore collections successfully, but I have to use the Firestore GUI to delete these collections before running the seed file again. I am doing this as follows:

```
const userData = [{},...]
let promises = [];
userData.forEach((obj) => promises.push(addDoc(collection(db, "users"), obj)));
Promise.all(promises);
```

Is there a way to:

- Implement a function to clear the existing collections before running the code above? (Google docs suggested this may not be a good idea)
- Stop the file running once it has added userData (currently, when the code above is executed, it doesn't terminate itself in Node, I have to use ctrl+c).

Thanks!

I have tried adding the data using the above method (which works). I looked at the Firestore docs for deleting collections using Node, but it suggests that is not a good idea.